# The 2-norm of the integral vs the integral of the 2-norm

Tags: analysis, normed-spaces

I`m currently having some issues with a seemingly innocent problem. I would like to show that

$$\Bigg\|\int_\mathbb{R}\begin{pmatrix}A(x)\\B(x)\end{pmatrix}dx\Bigg\|_2 \leq \int_{\mathbb{R}}\Bigg\|\begin{pmatrix}A(x)\\B(x)\end{pmatrix}\Bigg\|_2dx$$

Where $A(x),B(x) \in L^2(\mathbb{R})$ and the two norm is defined as
$$\Bigg\|\begin{pmatrix}A(x)\\B(x)\end{pmatrix}\Bigg\|_2=\sqrt{|A(x)|^2+|B(x)|^2}$$

I've asked around and people have tended to say "that's very simple" and then spent half an hour staring at it. I've tried plugging stuff in and it seems to hold but I do need a proof. Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks in advance

Comment: Since $\lVert\cdot\rVert_2$ is a norm, isn't it essentially the triangle inequality? (google "integral triangle inequality", for instance)

Comment: Your $2$-norm takes two things as argument, as you've defined it.  So what does it mean to take the $2$-norm of an integral which is just one argument?

Comment: @GregoryGrant Isn't the integral of a vector a vector? (i.e., it's the component-wise integral)

Comment: @GregoryGrant the integral of a vector is a vector. One can see this if they write out the vector as a sum.

Comment: @ClementC. Oh you mean like  ${{\int_{\Bbb R}A(x)dx}\choose{\int_{\Bbb R}B(x)dx}}$?

Comment: @GregoryGrant Yes.

Comment: @ClementC. the integral triangle inequality cannot be applied to the two norm (as far as i`m aware).

Comment: @GregoryGrant exactly (as far asi know)

Comment: @OliverBrace Err... this may be me being confused, but *why* would that be the case?

Comment: As far as I know $\|\cdot\|_2$ mostly refers to the spectral norm of a matrix.

Comment: @Vim ?! No. It is notation for the [$2$-norm](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/L2-Norm.html). It mostly refers to itself, and can (and does) apply to things that are not matrices or linear operators (but, if you deal with matrices, the $2$-norm does induce the spectral norm).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's very simple. hehe... (Note you actually want to assume $A,B\in L^1(\Bbb R)$, not $L^2$.)

**Edit:** Morally the same argument works for a Banach-space valued function; see **Below**.

To make things easier to type I'm going to revise the notation. Suppose that $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R^2$; we want to show that $$\left|\left|\int f(x)\,dx\right|\right|_2\le\int||f(x)||_2\,dx.$$Let $$v=\int f(x)\,dx\in\Bbb R^2.$$Then $$||v||_2^2=v\cdot v=v\cdot\int f(x)\,dx=\int v\cdot f(x)\,dx\le\int||v||_2||f(x)||_2\,dx=||v||_2\int||f(x)||_2\,dx.$$Divide by $||v||_2$: $$||v||_2\le\int||f(x)||_2\,dx.$$

**Below** One can give a similar argument if $f:S\to X$ where $X$ is a Banach space and $\mu$ is a measure on $S$. Let $$v=\int_Sf(t)\,d\mu(t)\in X.$$Suppose $\Lambda\in X^*$ and $||\Lambda||=1$. Then $$\Lambda v=\int\Lambda f(t)\,d\mu(t)\le\int||\Lambda||_{X^*}||f(t)||_X\,d\mu(t)=\int||f(t)||\,d\mu(t).$$Since this holds for every such $\Lambda$, Hahn-Banach shows that $||v||\le\int||f||\,d\mu$.

Comment: Thank you. You've made my project a bit more bearable.

Comment: Very nice answer for Pettis integrals in Banach spaces. But how readily can we equate the Pettis integral with the point-wise integral? I know one sufficient condition is for the point-evaluation functionals to be continuous.

Answer (score 9):

To give a more general picture, that does not use the special form of the $2$-norm being induced by the scalar product, we will show:

> **Proposition**. Suppose $X$ is a Banach space, $(S,\mathcal A, \mu)$ a measure space, and $f \colon S \to X$ is integrable. Then we have 
>   $$ \def\norm#1{\left\|#1\right\|}\norm{\int_S f \, d\mu} \le \int_S \norm {f(s)} \, d\mu(s) $$

*Proof*. We use the definition of the integral. If $f = \sum_i x_i\chi_{A_i}$ is a simple function, where the $A_i$ are disjoint, then $\norm{f(s)} = \sum_i \norm{x_i} \chi_{A_i}(s)$ and hence
\begin{align*}
  \norm{\int_S \sum_{i} x_i \chi_{A_i}d\mu} &= \norm{\sum_i \mu(A_i)x_i}\\
           &\le \sum_i \mu(A_i)\norm{x_i}\\
           &= \int_S \sum_{i}\norm{x_i}\chi_{A_i} d\mu\\
           &= \int_S \norm{f(s)}\, d\mu(s)
\end{align*}
If $f$ is integrable, choose simple functions $f_n$ such that $f_n \to f$ almost everywhere and $\lim_n\int_S f \, d\mu = \int_S f_n \, d\mu$ we have
\begin{align*}
  \norm{\int_S f\, d\mu} &= \lim_n \norm{\int_S f_n\, d\mu}\\
                         &\le \lim_n \int_S \norm{f_n(s)}\, d\mu(s)\\
                         &= \int_S \norm{f(s)}\, d\mu(s)
\end{align*}

Comment: Or one can give an argument in the Banach-space case that's precisely analogous to the argument using the fact that the $2$-norm is induced by an inner product... see edit to my answer.

Comment: Both arguments are worth knowing; yours is more elementary, while I think it's fair to say that mine is simpler. (And there are related situations where someone who only knows one would be better off knowing the other...)

Comment: Thank you but the other answer is more specific to my problem.